# Web Deploy deleting IIS website custom configuration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5, webdeploy

I'm using Web Deploy (from VS2013) to publish an ASP.NET MVC site to an IIS 7.5.

I added some URL rewrite rules and custom HTTP response headers through IIS manager.

The problem is everytime I deploy a new version of the site, this extra configuration is deleted.

Is this the expected behaviour or is there something wrong? How can I keep these custom settings on each deploy?

**UPDATE**

So I understood I need to put these changes in the `web.config`. I'm trying to put them in the `Web.Release.config` but it's not being added to the deployed `web.config`. I guess I'm missing some `XDT:Transform` rule.

This is what I got in my `Web.Release.config` (yes, the publishing profile is using this Release config).

```
<configuration>
    <!-- some other stuff -->
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="*" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mydomain.com" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
      </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are these changes put into the web.config that is deployed? If you check the difference between your local web.config and the deployed (after the changes have been made), is there something that differs between the files?

Comment: @NoLifeKing No, as I said, the changes were made through IIS manager, not web.config. Do I need to make them through web.config?

Comment: Changes made in the IIS Manager changes the deployed web.config with the new values. Of course, there are exceptions to what is changed, not everything is put into the web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I understood I need to add this custom configuration in the web.config using `XDT:Transform`.

I added this to the `Web.Release.config` and it worked:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mydomain.com" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 4):

Turn the build action of your web.config to None.  That will prevent the file from being deployed each time you publish.

**Edit**

For inserting entire sections into a web.config from the web.release.config, you need the xdt:Transform="Insert" added like so:

```
<system.webServer xdt:Transform="Insert">
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="*" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mydomain.com" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
      </system.webServer>
```

Comment: But I do want to deploy the web.config file (I might have added something there). So it seems the only way is to add the custom configuration directly on the web.config right?

Comment: Publish will always overwrite the destination web.config.  There is no merging the two files.  You'll have to have to have the changes somewhere on a local web.config (the primary or the .Release.config) in order for the publish to push all changes with the correct server settings.

Comment: Good to now. I'll put those configs in the Web.Release.config. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Josh, can you check my answer again? I've updated it. I think I'm missing some XDT Transform rule...

Comment: Couldn't respond quick enough.  Glad you figured it out.